# How to check Fieldvalue in flutter with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, if-statement, google-cloud-firestore

in my App I want to check if the field which look like this (like : 1 or 0) is 1 or 0. I thought I could get the value from this field in firebase and could check if this is equal to 0. But thats not work. If someone know a way to do that it would be nice.

```
if(snapshot2.data.docs[index].get("liked") == 0){
                                                // do stuff
                                              }
```

Comment: Please make sure the question contains enough information that we can reproduce the problem by copy/pasting the code. Right now we have no way of knowing what `snapshot2` is. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obtain from Firestore single field value via Flutter. This is intended. To get a value you will have to get whole document and then use dot notation to get a value you need.

**Example:**

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userId)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
        try {
          dynamic nested = documentSnapshot.get(FieldPath(['address']));
          } on StateError catch(e) {
          print('No nested field exists!');
}
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
```

You can check docs and other examples [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage)

Comment: thanks but I cant use nested for my check I want to check if nested == 0 or 1. Because nested isnt found in my if statement